# Bad alignment of text fields in HTML

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why the first textbox is not aligned in the following HTML/CSS? ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ughjk/)).

```
<div class="gift_code_fields">
    <div class="gift_code_line">
        <div class="gift_code_line_header">
            <label for="1">1</label><span>:</span>
        </div>
        <input class="gift_code" id="gift_code_1" name="gift_code_1" type="text">

    </div>
    <div class="gift_code_line">
        <div class="gift_code_line_header">
            <label>2</label>
            <span>:</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="gift_code">
    </div>
    <div class="gift_code_line">
        <div class="gift_code_line_header">
            <label>3</label>
            <span>:</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="gift_code">
    </div>
    <div class="gift_code_line">
        <div class="gift_code_line_header">
            <label>4</label>
            <span>:</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="gift_code">
    </div>
</div>​
```

```
.gift_label{
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gift_code_section{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.gift_code_choose{
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.gift_code_fields{
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.add_gift_code{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gift_code {
  display: inline;
}

.gift_code_line_header{
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}​
```

Comment: Can't you spot the difference between the first one and the other ones? The difference should lead you to conclude that whitespace is significant in some way.

Comment: @CLuddy Not it's not. There are two ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Ok I see that now, just seems odd! Sorry :) If the code layout was consistent the issue wouldn't have happened.

Comment: @CLuddy No worries. And certainly, I'm always neurotic about code formatting, and it makes me cringe when I see haphazard formatting.

Comment: Strange though, I wouldn't have expected a CR between two HTML tags to have any effect. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Yes, I just don´t understand yet why it happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have put the `<span>` for colon on a new line for everything except the first one:

```
<label for="1">1</label><span>:</span>

<label for="2">2</label>
<span>:</span>
```

This is because, according to the HTML spec, any sequence of white-space characters is treated as a single space.

Comment: +1 for actually stating that it doesn't *have* to be a new line, and can be any amount or type of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Because you lack a line change before the `:`

You have

```
<label for="1">1</label><span>:</span>
```

Instead of

```
<label for="1">1</label>
            <span>:</span>
```

as for other lines.

You're welcome.

Comment: Can you see the space in the HTML?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a CR, it can be *any* whitespace.

Comment: @Tony its the whitespace between the label and the span that is missing, this is correct.

Comment: Why an enter should affect visualization?

Comment: It would be better to have similar lines. Type the return key when your cursor is between `label>` and `<span` and it works.

Comment: @Tony : because more than one spaces are considered just as one doesn't mean one is considered as none.

Comment: @Tony The reason this affects visualization is because, according to the HTML spec, any sequence of white-space characters is treated as a single space. A carriage-return is a white-space character, so it gets treated as a single space.

Comment: See my answer below, you were trying to set the width of the label wrapper but it wasn't being applied

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/ughjk/6/

```
.gift_code_line_header{
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

The width you set for the label wrapper won't be applied unless it's a block or inline-block element.

Comment: This is true, but somehow I think that the width may have been added in an attempt by the OP to solve the real problem which was the lack of whitespace. +1 though, correct and solves the problem.

Comment: This is the best answer - I hadn't even noticed there **was** any CSS in the Fiddle!!

Comment: Whitespace shouldn't be used to align things, bad practise. The width was the correct way to achieve it. Thanks for the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<div class="gift_code_line">
    <div class="gift_code_line_header">
        <label for="1">1</label><span>:</span>
    </div>
    <input class="gift_code" id="gift_code_1" name="gift_code_1" type="text">

</div>
```

with:

```
<div class="gift_code_line">
    <div class="gift_code_line_header">
        <label for="1">1</label>
        <span>:</span>
    </div>
    <input class="gift_code" id="gift_code_1" name="gift_code_1" type="text">

</div>
```